# Find an expression for the coefficient of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

I'm trying to find an expression for the coefficients of the Taylor series centered at zero of the function $$f(z)=\frac {e^{z^2}}{z-2}$$

As a hint I'm told to try and multiply through by $$z-2$$ and see where that leads me.. not very far I'm afraid..

$$\frac{f(0)}{0!}=\frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{1}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{f'(0)}{1!}=\frac{-\frac{1}{4}}{1}=-\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\frac{f''(0)}{2!}=\frac{-\frac{5}{8}}{2}=-\frac{5}{16}$$
$$\frac{f'''(0)}{3!}=\frac{-\frac{5}{16}}{6}=-\frac{5}{96}$$
$$\frac{f''''(0)}{4!}=\frac{-\frac{13}{32}}{24}=-\frac{13}{768}$$

The above should be the first 5 coefficients unless I made a mistake somewhere. Is there some pattern to this?

Comment: I think you made some mistakes... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Maclaurin+e%5E%28z%5E2%29%2F%28z-2%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{e^{z^2}}{z-2}=-\frac{1}{2}e^{z^2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!2^{m+1}}z^{2n+m}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k$$
where
$$a_k=-\sum_{m=0,\;\;k-m:\;even}^{k}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{k-m}{2}\right)!\;2^{m+1}}.$$

Further simplification:
$$a_{2s}=-\frac{1}{2^{2s+1}}\sum_{t=0}^s\frac{4^t}{t!}\;\;\text{ and }\;\; a_{2s+1}=-\frac{1}{2^{2s+2}}\sum_{t=0}^s\frac{4^t}{t!}$$

Closed-form: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum_%28t%3D0%29%5Es+4%5Et%2Ft%21